# how can I compare two lists in python and if I have matches ~> I want matches and next value from another list

Tags: python, list, compare

a = [’bww’, ’1’, ’23’, ’honda’, ’2’, ’55’, ’ford’, ’11’, ’88’, ’tesla’, ’15’, ’1’, ’kia’, ’2’, ’3’]

b = [’ford’, ’honda’]

should return all matches and next value from list a

Result -> [’ford’, ’11’, ’honda’, ’2’]
or even better [’ford 11’, ’honda 2’]

I am new with python and asking help

Comment: It's nit a valid python code...what are the items in your lists? Strings, tuples?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming all are in `string` type also assuming after every name in the `list a` there will be a number next to him.

**Code:-**

```
a = ['bww', '1', 'honda', '2', 'ford', '11', 'tesla', '15', 'nissan', '2']
b = ['ford', 'honda']

res=[]
for check in b:
    for index in range(len(a)-1):
        if check==a[index]:
            res.append(check+" "+a[index+1])
print(res)
```

**Output:-**

```
['ford 11', 'honda 2']
```

**List comprehension**

**Code:-**

```
a = ['bww', '1', 'honda', '2', 'ford', '11', 'tesla', '15', 'nissan', '2']
b = ['ford', 'honda']

res=[check+" "+a[index+1] for check in b  for index in range(len(a)-1) if check==a[index]]

print(res) #Same output
```

Comment: You seem to have changed the source data to suit your code. Is that wise? Normally one would write code to suit the data!

Comment: @Fred see the first comment in my answer. he said yes all are in string type..! And he acknowledged my answer.. I think i assumed right so the data seems to be same as mine..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a neat one-liner to solve what you are looking for. It uses a list comprehension, which iterates over 2 items (bi-gram) of the list at once and then combines the matching items with their next item using `.join()`

```
[' '.join([i,j]) for i,j in zip(a,a[1:]) if i in b]  #<------
```

```
['honda 2', 'ford 11']
```

#### EXPLANATION:

1. You can use `zip(a, a[1:])` to iterate over 2 items in the list at once (bi-gram), as a rolling window of size 2. This works as follows.

[image]

2. Next you can compare the first item `i[k]` in each tuple `(i[k],i[k+1])` with elements from list `b`, using `if i in b`
3. If it matches, you can then keep that tuple, and use `' '.join([i,j])` to join them into 1 string as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the data to suit the code (which some responders seem to think is appropriate) try this:

```
GROUP = 3

a = ['bmw', '1', '23', 'honda', '2', '55', 'ford', '11', '88', 'tesla', '15', '1', 'kia', '2', '3']
b = ['ford', 'honda']
c = [f'{a[i]} {a[i+1]}' for i in range(0, len(a)-1, GROUP) if a[i] in b]

print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
['honda 2', 'ford 11']
```

**Note:**

The assumption here is that input data are presented in groups of three but only the first two values in each triplet are needed.

If the assumption about grouping is wrong then:

```
c = [f'{a[i]} {a[i+1]}' for i in range(len(a)-1) if a[i] in b]
```

...which will be less efficient

Answer (score -1):

I hope ths will help you

```
a = ['bww', 1, 'honda', 2, 'ford', 11, 'tesla', 15, 'nissan', 2]
b = ['ford', 'honda']
ls=[]
for item in b:
    if a.__contains__(item):
        ls.append((item+" "+str(a[a.index(item)+1])))
print(ls)
```